# Embed Google Maps only showing top left corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, google-maps

I am using a WordPress plugin for integrated Google Maps into the website, but I can only see the top left corner: http://prntscr.com/4i3eus

I looked at the other questions and someone said to use this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

However map is undefined... When I resize my browser the map loads however. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Well in this case the variable of the map object is the map passed in trigger method . If your map object is referenced by a different variable you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case the variable of the `map object` is the map passed in `trigger` method . If your `map object` is referenced by a different variable you should use that.

Comment: How do I find that variable?

Comment: Do you use a plugin for the map or did you write it?

Comment: Using the Ready! Google Maps plugin

Comment: Then you should seek a solution from within the plugin. You can't find the variable that easily and if you did, the variable of the map object will not be global, thus it will not be accessible that easily. Check the forums of this plugin. There must be already some solution since I see that is a pretty mature plugin.